# Disable application layout for custom Facebook share button in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I've implemented custom buttons for Twitter and Facebook sharing in my Rails app, and thus have had to use Javascript below to open popups when they are clicked:

```
$('.popup, #fbShare').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=400,scrollbars=yes");
return false;
});
```

The Twitter button works fine but the Facebook share button keeps attempting to yield the default application layout and giving an error message of:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with id=undefined"

The javascript file is named search.js.erb, and I'm trying to share a link from the home page, so I would assume I need to add something to the ApplicationController, but this error message makes it seem like the error is with UsersController (which does route to root, but I'm not on that user page when attempting to share).

I've had a look around and found two solutions proffered: 1 is  to add

```
 layout proc{|c| c.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
```

to the ApplicationController: that doesn't seem to work. Another is to add

```
 def respond
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :layout => false }
end
end
```

to the controller; I've tried adding this to both Application and UsersController, with no luck. I've managed to use "render :layout => false" before with success but am unsure how to implement it in this case.

Comment: What URL is opened when you click the fbShare button?

Comment: I've set the link to <a href="http://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php...>, but when I click the link it opens http://localhost:3000/undefined . The link works fine if I open it in a new tab, though, and the function works fine for the Twitter share button.

Answer (score 0):

Added the "popup" class to the Facebook link as well and removed the #fbShare from the jQuery, now it works, I think the id was confusing the Rails app into thinking it was a user id?